# Any way to control excessive CPU usage on various web-site when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When using various websites (like twitter.com or the nypost.com) my Chrome CPU usage explodes and the fans start spinning. Is there any way to throttle Chrome's background CPU usage for web-workers? Happy to write a chrome extension or change something in the dev panel... thanks!